# Java Could Not create the java virtual machine

Tags: java, minecraft

Hi  I was trying to code a minecraft launcher under forge and I got this error:

```
[OpenLauncherLib] Launching Minecraft

[OpenLauncherLib] Successfully launched

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was 
deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.

Unrecognized VM option 'CMSIncrementalMode'

Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.

Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

here is my code code :

```java
public class Launcher {

    public static final GameVersion SC_VERSION = new GameVersion("1.7.10", GameType.V1_7_10);

    public static final GameInfos SC_INFOS = new GameInfos("Lunaria", SC_VERSION ,true ,new GameTweak[] {GameTweak.FORGE});

    public static final File SC_DIR = SC_INFOS.getGameDir();
    
    private static AuthInfos authInfos;

    private static Thread updateThread;
    
    public static void auth(String username, String password) throws AuthenticationException{

        Authenticator authentificator = new Authenticator(Authenticator.MOJANG_AUTH_URL, AuthPoints.NORMAL_AUTH_POINTS);
        AuthResponse response = authentificator.authenticate(AuthAgent.MINECRAFT, username, password, "");
        authInfos = new AuthInfos(response.getSelectedProfile().getName(), response.getAccessToken(), response.getSelectedProfile().getId());
    }
    
    public static void update() throws Exception {
        SUpdate su = new SUpdate("https://launcherpanel.000webhostapp.com/", SC_DIR);
        su.addApplication(new FileDeleter());
        
        updateThread = new Thread() {
            private int val;
            private int max;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(!this.isInterrupted()) {
                    if(BarAPI.getNumberOfFileToDownload() == 0){
                        LauncherFrame.getInstance().getLauncherPanel().setInfoText("Verification des fichers...");
                        continue;
                    }
                    val = (int) (BarAPI.getNumberOfTotalDownloadedBytes() / 1000);
                    max = (int) (BarAPI.getNumberOfTotalBytesToDownload() / 1000);
                    
                    
                    
                    LauncherFrame.getInstance().getLauncherPanel().getProgressBar().setMaximum(max);
                    LauncherFrame.getInstance().getLauncherPanel().getProgressBar().setValue(val);
                    
                    LauncherFrame.getInstance().getLauncherPanel().setInfoText("Telechargement des fichiers... " 
                    + BarAPI.getNumberOfDownloadedFiles() + "/" + BarAPI.getNumberOfFileToDownload() +
                    Swinger.percentage(val, max) + "%");
                    
                }
            }
        };
        updateThread.start();
        
        su.start();
        if(updateThread != null)
        updateThread.interrupt();
    }
    
    public static void launch() throws IOException {
        GameLauncher gameLauncher = new GameLauncher(SC_INFOS,GameFolder.BASIC,authInfos);
        Process p = gameLauncher.launch();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            
        }
        LauncherFrame.getInstance().setVisible(false);
        try {
            p.waitFor();;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
    
    public static void interruptThread() {
        updateThread.interrupt();
    }
    
}
```

thanks to answer.
edit : im under mac os X 10.10

Comment: Remove the VM option `CMSIncrementalMode`

Comment: @dan1st I dont Have Launcher profile option in my launcher i have ram selector

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look to be about your launcher, it looks to be about the JVM being passed a parameter it is unable to handle. Your program is commonly loaded like this:

- Your program executes your code
- The JVM is an environment, in which your program is executed
- Your operating system is the environment in which the JVM is executed

Currently none of your code is executed, because the JVM, where it *would be executed* is unable to execute itself.

To reiterate, the structure is like this:

OS > JVM > JAR

You are currently looking at this part:

OS > JVM > **JAR**

You should be looking at this part:

OS > **JVM** > JAR

As @dan1st stated, currently a parameter `CMSIncrementalMode` is passed as an argument to your JVM. It cannot handle that argument and refuses to run. None of your code gets executed. You can derive this from the error message:

```
Unrecognized VM option 'CMSIncrementalMode'

Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
```